# Redux reducer to fetch, like, and dislike posts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, immutability

I have made a like functionality with Redux and React Native.

I have a reducer with initial state `posts = []` and my reducer looks like

```
const initialState = {
  posts: []
};

function postReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_POSTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: action.posts
      };

    case LIKE_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.posts.map(post => {
          if (post._id === action.postId) {
            return {
              ...post,
              likes: !!post.likes ? post.likes.concat(action.userId) : [action.userId]
            }
          }
          return post;
        })
      };

    case UNLIKE_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.posts.map(post => {
          if (post._id === action.postId) {
            return {
              ...post,
              likes: post.likes.filter(userId => userId !== action.userId)
            }
          }
          return post;
        })
      };

    default:
      return state
  }
};
```

I know that I can not mutate the `posts` array in my state, so I have to return a new array of posts where I have modified the post that a user tries to like/unlike.

It seems to work very well, but it's daunting slow. I only have very few posts, but I still have to wait almost a second for it the like to be visible.

Is this the right approach? Am I storing my posts correctly as a simple array in the state? I'm not sure what the alternative is, but I have, for instance, seen in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/kenny-hibino/hackafy-native/blob/master/app/redux/reducers/posts.js) that it can be done different, although I don't fully understand the structure of it.

Comment: When you say "takes a second for a like to be visible": have you tried doing any kind of benchmarking?  It's unlikely that the reducer would be taking anywhere near that much time.  Would be helpful to better know what is causing the delays. The code looks correct otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that this is slow and tedious, but it is necessary if you want to ensure you don't mutate state and stick to the correct patterns that are suggested.

That said you have a few options, an obvious one is to make helper `functions` that solve the common problems you face, however a (personally) better solution is to use **[`ImmutableJS`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)**. It will provide you with three things:

The first is it guarantees you aren't mutating state as all changes return a new and different copy.

The second is a convenient API that will allow you to do your mutations with ease instead of using awkward syntax to work around vanilla javascript.

The third is more of a minor benefit but you get access to Immutable types such as `List`, `Map`, a variety of `Collections` and define your own types with `Records`, which I recomment to use for each reducer state as you can declare the shape of the state, and only mutate the defined properties, instead of adding new ones.

With `Immutable` a single part of your reducer would look like this:

```
case FETCH_POSTS:
  return state.set('posts', action.posts);
case LIKE_POST:
  let posts = state.posts.map( (p) => {
      if (p.id === action.postId) {
         return p.set('likes', 'something');
      }
      return p;
  }
```

It gets even more exciting if you build your state off a `Record`, so you would have:

```
export default Record({
   posts: List(),
}, 'SocialRecord');
```

Which would then let you have `state.get('posts')` or `state.posts` and still have `immutable` functionality as `Record`s have `getters`.

Check out the docs for more information:

**[Immutable Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/)**